# How to export (oracle) database table to excel sheet using laravel

Tags: excel, laravel, export

I am trying to export a (query structured) table (called formal) to excel using laravel. So far I can show table in browser as html using this blade. I want when user presses Export to excel button to export to excel (my blade is below):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="el">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Studies</title>
</head>
<body>
<b>Schedule: {{ $key }}</b>
<br>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Lesson Category</th>
        <th>Lesson Code</th>
        <th>Lesson Title</th>
        <th>Lesson Department</th>
          /* extra columns
           ....
          */
        <th>Audience</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($star as $v2)
    <tr>
        <th>{{ $v2->lesson_category }}</th>
        <td>{{ $v2->lesson_code }}</td>
        <td>{{ $v2->lesson_title }}</td>
        <td>{{ $v2->lesson_dep }}</td>
        /* extra columns
           ....
        */
        <td>{{ $v2->audience}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
<br>

<form action='/programma'>
    <input type="submit" value="New Search" />
</form>

<br>

<form action='/export'>
    <input type="submit" value="Export to excel" />   //I want this button to 
                                                      //export to excel
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I have followed this guide with no success. 
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/installation.html
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/

The maatwebsite/excel has been installed successfully. But no excel is downloaded.

Comment: Please can you show the controller code for the `/export` route?

Comment: What error do you get after calling '/export' ? Do you have all required extensions enabled server-side?

Comment: Hi guys! I finally did it, but there is still a problem. The exported excel does not have titles on top of each columns. Could you help me a little bit? I will answer my question myself and any idea is very very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. I did it to export to excel file.

Below is my solution so far. Thank you all!

1) web.php

```
Route::get('/exagogi','UsersController@export');
```

2) UsersController.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Exports\UsersExport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class UsersController extends Controller 
{
    public function export() 
    {
        return Excel::download(new UsersExport, 'result.xlsx');
    }
}
```

3) UsersExport.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings; 

class UsersExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        return User::all();
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'Lesson Category',
            'Lesson Title',
            'Lesson Department'
        // etc


        ];
    }
}
```